# PHPMailer sending by Local instead of remote SMTP (GMAIL)

Tags: php, amazon-ec2, smtp, gmail, phpmailer

So i have installed cPanel on a EC2 server.
But to send E-mails using PHP I'm using PHPMailer by this Code:

```
$mail = new PHPMailer();
//Tell PHPMailer to use SMTP
$mail->isSMTP();
//Set the hostname of the mail server
$mail->Host = 'smtp.gmail.com';
//Set the SMTP port number - likely to be 25, 465 or 587
$mail->Port = 587;
//Whether to use SMTP authentication
$mail->SMTPAuth = true;
$mail->SMTPDebug = 3;
//Set the encryption system to use - ssl (deprecated) or tls
$mail->SMTPSecure = 'tls';
//Username to use for SMTP authentication
$mail->Username = 'email@mysite.com';
//Password to use for SMTP authentication
$mail->Password = 'mypass';
//Set who the message is to be sent from
$mail->setFrom('from@mysite.com', 'My Site');
//Set who the message is to be sent to
$mail->addAddress('email@othersite.com');
// Set charset
$mail->CharSet = 'utf-8';
//Set the subject line
$mail->Subject = 'Subject';
//Read an HTML message body from an external file, convert referenced images to embedded,
//convert HTML into a basic plain-text alternative body
$mail->msgHTML('my Message');

//send the message, check for errors
echo $mail->send();
```

And the PHPMailer debug output is:

```
SMTP -> FROM SERVER:220-myserver.com ESMTP Exim 4.85 #2 Fri, 15 May 2015 14:34:35 -0300 220-We do not authorize the use of this system to transport unsolicited, 220 and/or bulk e-mail. 
SMTP -> FROM SERVER: 250-myserver.com Hello ip-123-45-67-89.sa-east-1.compute.internal [123.45.67.89] 250-SIZE 52428800 250-8BITMIME 250-PIPELINING 250-AUTH PLAIN LOGIN 250-STARTTLS 250 HELP 
SMTP -> FROM SERVER:220 TLS go ahead 
SMTP -> FROM SERVER: 250-myserver.com Hello ip-123-45-67-89.sa-east-1.compute.internal [123.45.67.89] 250-SIZE 52428800 250-8BITMIME 250-PIPELINING 250-AUTH PLAIN LOGIN 250 HELP 
SMTP -> FROM SERVER:250 OK 
SMTP -> FROM SERVER:250 Accepted 
SMTP -> FROM SERVER:354 Enter message, ending with "." on a line by itself 
SMTP -> FROM SERVER:250 OK id=1YtJVN-0007Lr-Us 
SMTP -> FROM SERVER:221 myserver.com closing connection 
1
```

The PHPMailer should use Gmail SMTP server to send the e-mail, But instead is using the local SMTP server.

I'm using gmail to notify my clients that are registered on my server but the DNS is not set to my server yet.

I tried the exact same code on other server that does not have cpanel and SMTP server and it worked fine with gmail response.

```
SMTP -> FROM SERVER:220 mx.google.com ESMTP 72sm1238383qhx.32 - gsmtp 
SMTP -> FROM SERVER: 250-mx.google.com at your service, [123.45.67.89] 250-SIZE 35882577 250-8BITMIME 250-STARTTLS 250-ENHANCEDSTATUSCODES 250-PIPELINING 250-CHUNKING 250 SMTPUTF8 
SMTP -> FROM SERVER:220 2.0.0 Ready to start TLS 
SMTP -> FROM SERVER: 250-mx.google.com at your service, [123.45.67.89] 250-SIZE 35882577 250-8BITMIME 250-AUTH LOGIN PLAIN XOAUTH2 PLAIN-CLIENTTOKEN XOAUTH 250-ENHANCEDSTATUSCODES 250-PIPELINING 250-CHUNKING 250 SMTPUTF8 
SMTP -> FROM SERVER:250 2.1.0 OK 72sm1238383qhx.32 - gsmtp 
SMTP -> FROM SERVER:250 2.1.5 OK 72sm1238383qhx.32 - gsmtp 
SMTP -> FROM SERVER:354 Go ahead 72sm1238383qhx.32 - gsmtp 
SMTP -> FROM SERVER:250 2.0.0 OK 1431704928 72sm1238383qhx.32 - gsmtp 
SMTP -> FROM SERVER:221 2.0.0 closing connection 72sm1238383qhx.32 - gsmtp
```

Can someone help me?

Comment: Talk to your host. Maybe they have something that overrides connections.

Comment: Can also test the connection using curl or open a stream to `smtp.gmail.com:587`

Comment: I'm my host.
root@server [~]# curl smtp.gmail.com:587
220 mx.google.com ESMTP 102sm1484452qgn.37 - gsmtp
502 5.5.1 Unrecognized command. 102sm1484452qgn.37 - gsmtp

Comment: Seems your script can make the connection to the host address. So why is your server connecting to the wrong thing?

Comment: One thing that's a bit odd here - you have specified SMTPDebug = 3, yet it's only showing what you would see if you set SMTPDebug = 1. Are you using latest PHPMailer (5.2.10)?

Comment: Yes, the PHPMailer is updated.
I talked to the developer and he said that is some setting on the php or something.
Because pings and curl can enter the gmail server, but only the php can't.
I really don't know what is, Probally cpanel stuff.

Comment: if you want to confirm that the issue is with your host and not phpmailer or its configuration, you could try a quick test using a different php email library such as [pennypost](https://bitbucket.org/ghorwood/pennypost).